Encrytion with Passkeys - PRF extension and hmacCreateSecret extension, which one to use?
On latest version of Chrome (130.0.6723.117 as of today), the Passkey API in navigator.credentials supports both prf and hmacCreateSecret as extensions. Both APIs are very similar: they accept 1 required salt and 1 optional salt for key rotation purpose. The outputs can be used to derive a key for symmetric encryption.
There are 2 questions:

Do these two extensions serve the same purpose?
If I want to create a symmetric key that can be exported (to be used by an encryption service outside of the authenticator, for example), which extension should I use?


I would highly recommend that you use passkeys only for their intended purpose: authentication. Using them for other purposes can cause user confusion and result in lost user data (as there's no real way to properly inform users of their use during their lifetime)

Why do these extensions exist if passkeys' only intended purpose is authentication? The specifications clearly state that these extensions are for encryption and decryption purposes. Just as passkeys are good for web authentication, they are also perfect for user's encryption key management, especially in self-sovereign solutions

Because some organizations have decided to accept the risk and take a dependency on it. I can't stop anyone from using it, but I can recommend against it.

The prf extension is the correct one to use at the WebAuthn level. hmac_secret is a lower-level extension which is specific to security keys.
